# how i can use a parameter two time in a sql segment in oracle

Tags: c#, oracle10g, oledb

hi i hope have nice days

in oracle when i use a parameter two time in sql segment i got error

like that

```
Select OPS$ASY.UNTARTAB.EEA_DOV,OPS$ASY.UNTARTAB.EEA_EOV from OPS$ASY.UNTARTAB

   WHERE OPS$ASY.UNTARTAB.EEA_DOV = :X OR OPS$ASY.UNTARTAB.EEA_EOV = :X
```

ERROR IS : ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

but i use this segment i have not problems but i need use A parameter two times

```
Select OPS$ASY.UNTARTAB.EEA_DOV,OPS$ASY.UNTARTAB.EEA_EOV from OPS$ASY.UNTARTAB

   WHERE OPS$ASY.UNTARTAB.EEA_DOV = :X OR OPS$ASY.UNTARTAB.EEA_EOV = :Y
```

Comment: +1 For hoping we are having nice days :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i understand how i slove this problem

i must add two time parameter x with same value

Have Nice Day